# C# iTextSharp: split table

Tags: c#, split, itext, pdfptable

i got my pdf like this.

https://drive.google.com/a/mahidol.edu/file/d/0B9vSVV3dDAmFZDkwWXdfYWNDc2M/view

first, on Page 1 i use rowspan on the first column when it splited, bottom line not be equal. i want the line to be equal.

second, on Page 2 when table splited, on first column, i want to repeat column value again on new page.

thank you so much.

ps: I use nest table (fill table into another table). i am not sure, this is cause of problem or not?

Comment: The cause is probably that you're using an old version of iTextSharp. Can you confirm this?

Comment: i use iTextSharp 5.5.3.0

Comment: For someone that have same problem as me, I fixed by don't use nest table.